# Reason for sorbitol synthesis in human body

Tags: human-biology, enzymes, glucose, diabetes-mellitus

Sorbitol has been proved to be a major contributor to development of complications due to chronic diabetes.
It forms in retina, lens, kidneys, peripheral nerves, ovaries and seminal vesicles by the action of aldol reductase on glucose. It only forms sorbitol when glucose concentration gets high as it has high Km.
It is seen that it accumulates in retina, kidney, lens and peripheral nerves as they lack the enzyme sorbitol dehydrogenase to convert it to fructose however ovaries and seminal vesicles have it so they are saved from accumulation.
Sorbitol accumulates and the membranes being impermeable to it, it results in drawing in of water by virtue of its osmotic activity.
I wonder why is it even being formed in the first place in retina, lens, kidney and peripheral nerves when it serves no function there?
I tried searching for any possible functions it may have in these tissues but apparently it has a role only in formation of fructose for sperms in seminal fluid.